# R increase space horizontally between overlapping points geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, space, overlapping

I have a data table similar to the following:
[image]
I am trying to plot points (categorical variable “Data”) corresponding to each patient per week (some longitudinal data are missing) but I need to increase a bit the distance between points of categorical variable “Data” in the horizontal axis. I am trying with the following code:

```
df=read.delim("/Volumes/test.txt",header=TRUE,sep="\t")

df=df[order(df$ID),]

df$Timepoint<-factor(df$Timepoint,levels=c("w0","w1","w6","w7","w8","w10"))
df$Phase<-factor(df$Phase,levels=c("pre_treat","treat","post_treat"))

ggplot(df,aes(x=Timepoint,y=ID,shape=Data))+
  geom_point(aes(color=Data,shape=Data),size=3.5, position = position_jitter(w = 0.1, h = 0))+
  facet_wrap(~Phase,scales="free_x")+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,0,17))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black","black","gray60"))+
  theme_bw()+ylab("ID")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

The problem I am encountering is that points are too close and the order of each symbol seems randomly represented. 
[image]

I tried with both position_jitter and position_dodge but I still obtain diagonal-oriented or overlapping point.
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use position_dodge2() instead of position_dodge() and set the expand(..) argument inside scale_x_discrete to see the points:

```
df = expand.grid(
  ID=c("P1","P2"),
  Timepoint = c("w0","w1","w6"),
  Phase = c("pre_treat","treat","post_treat"),
  Data  =c("Transcriptomics","Methylation","IM")
)

#sample some data
df=df[runif(45)>0.1,]


ggplot(df,aes(x=Timepoint,y=ID,shape=Data))+
  geom_point(aes(color=Data,shape=Data),size=3.5, 
             position = position_dodge2(w = 0.75))+
  facet_wrap(~Phase,scales="free_x")+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,0,17))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black","black","gray60"))+
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0.1, 0.5))+
  theme_bw()+ylab("ID")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]